# Remove Encryption.Some of my Project files in c# have green text

Tags: c#, encryption

Not sure where to post this but there you go

I have an external disk drive
I dont remember encrypting however some project files are green and when moving to another computer it does not let me.

How do you remove the encryption?
Using windows 7.

Any suggestion? Googling did not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the file(s)/folder(s), select properties, hit the Advanced button, and uncheck the Encrypt checkbox

Comment: WORKED.How silly of me